# Heating NaOH solutions

Tags: solutions, home-experiment

I am trying to determine the best heat at which to use an NaOH solution to clean a textile fiber. This is being done, carefully, in Asian villages.

The raw material is ribbons of bark peeled from a plant stalk. The fiber adheres to the inside of the bark. We need to loosen the bark, at least. Having it degrade and fully separate would be better as long as that doesn't damage the fiber too much.

At present, we prepare a relatively weak caustic solution and bring it to a boil with bark ribbon in it. It sits and cools overnight and then the material is removed and washed. So, the temperature ranges from ambient (22-34C) to 100C and back to ambient.

I will figure out the % of NaOH we have in the water, but I'm hoping to reduce the quantity we use as it's one of our biggest costs.

I think boiling the solution is causing it to be less powerful in treating the bark/fiber, but I'm not at all sure. I am, obviously, not a scientist!

Thanks.

Comment: We use 30kg of NaOH flakes per 1000 liters of water. I'm not sure how to calculate this as a solution.

Comment: I don't think boiling the solution is causing it to be less powerful. If anything, it is probably the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial solution consists of 30 kg NaOH in 1000 kg of water; it will treat a certain amount of bark ribbon. I suspect that the final pH of the solution is much less than the original pH; i.e., the solution gets used up by reacting with the plant material. You mention that one of the biggest costs is for NaOH.

Optimizing the procedure could involve the reaction temperature, as you suggest. Generally, heating makes reactions go faster and more completely. Occasional stirring might be helpful. One way to check on the reaction is to measure the pH with (commercial) paper strips designed for high pH measurements; as the pH drops below some value, the useful part of the reaction may stop.

One way to reduce cost could be to wash the bark with plain water before treating it with NaOH solution. The purpose of the plain water wash would be to remove water soluble sugars, starches and acids that otherwise consume the NaOH, leaving it to do the harder job of disadhering the fibers.

Another way could be to substitute sodium carbonate (soda ash: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_carbonate) for the sodium hydroxide. Prices vary for many reasons, and it is not clear whether you need the high pH of NaOH if you can boil it and allow the solution to cool slowly. You could consider insulating the kettle to keep it warmer longer. Sodium carbonate is available in many forms, from anhydrous to monohydrate to decahydrate, and technical grades in various purities; you will need a little chemistry to calculate the actual cost of the operation with each of these variations. Sodium carbonate's lower pH would be more gentle to the desired fibers.

I checked previous prices in the US: 1 mole of NaOH was about 3 to 4 times as expensive as a half mole of Na<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub>.H<sub>2</sub>O (the monohydrate). If the pH of sodium carbonate (~11.5) is adequate for the operation, you may not need the (initial) pH ~14 of your 3% solution (0.75 M). And you could use more sodium carbonate if that helps.

Another possibility for reducing costs is liquid (50%) NaOH. This is usually cheaper than pellets or flakes, and may be more convenient (faster dissolution) but does present an extra hazard of splashes and spills. Eye protection is a requirement, because a splash in the eye means blindness. (Of course, a splash of 3% NaOH is just about as dangerous.)

Comment: THANK YOU! James Gaidis. It's so difficult to get help with this. I'm trying to learn the science to make decisions and your answer really helps.

I'm going to read this a couple of times and then get back to you with more questions, I'm sure.

We tried soda ash a long time ago. I don't remember the results, but we were trying it in complete ignorance. Historically, villagers used ash from their fires, so a lower pH base is possible.

Comment: Is it possible to speak with you directly? I could really use some help with this as I have so many more questions.

Comment: @EllieBelly: I've asked how to do that. I'll get back to you when I find out.

Comment: @EllieBelly: Put your email address in your profile. After we establish communications, you can modify your profile and delete your email address.